# Mixed intial terminal value data problem using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second-order ODE using Laplace transform where the initial values are given at different times:

$$ y''(t)+y(t)=r(t), \;y(0)=0, \;y'(\pi)=1 $$  $$ $$

\begin{align*} 
r(t)&=t, \;  t<1 \\
r(t)&=0,\; t>1 .
\end{align*}

Using the Laplace on both sides you get:

$$ s^2 \mathcal{L}y -sy(0)-y'(0) +\mathcal{L}y= \mathcal{L}r $$
$$ (s^2 +1)\mathcal{L}y = \mathcal{L}r+y'(0)$$
$$ \mathcal{L}y=\frac{\mathcal{L}r}{s^2 +1}+ \frac{y'(0)}{s^2 +1}. $$

I know how to find the inverse Laplace transform of: 
$$ \frac{\mathcal{L}r}{s^2 +1}, $$

and I also know that:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{y'(0)}{s^2 +1}\right)=y'(0)\sin(t).$$

But I don't know how to find the constant $y'(0)$, or if there is something else I have to do; help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\mathcal{L}(r(t)) = \frac{1-(1+s)e^{-s}}{s^2}
$$

Considering $y(0),\ y'(0)$ as generic constants we have

$$
Y(s) = \frac{s^3 C_1+s^2 C_2-s+1-(1+s)e^{-s}}{s^2 \left(s^2+1\right)}
$$

and after inversion

$$
y(t) = t-\theta (t-1) (t+\sin (1-t)-\cos (1-t))+\sin (t) \left(C_2-1\right)+C_1 \cos (t)
$$

now the constants $C_1,\ C_2$ are determined according the conditions

$$
y(0) = 0\\
y'(\pi) = 1
$$

NOTE

Here $r(t)$ is considered as

$$
r(t) = \cases{t < 0\to r(t) = 0\\0 \le t < 1\to r(t) = t\\ t > 1\to r(t) = 0}
$$